# Is there an ambiguity in time in the absence of clocks?

Tags: time, emergent-properties

Imagine 2 clocks space 2 meters apart with a vacuum in between.

These are macroscopic objects with which we can measure time.

But in between these, according to general relativity, we can foliate time in a variety of ways. For a point right between these 2 clocks, the folliations could have a maximum diference of 2m/c = 6.6 nanoseconds difference. Since there are no macroscopic objects in the vacuum to time-order these foliations.

Therefor could we conclude that if there is no absolute time, and we can only measure time by macroscopic objects according to thermodynamical principles, that in the center of this vaccum time is ambiguous to 6.6 nanoseconds? i.e. the time taken for a beam of light to travel from one clock to another?

Comment: What maintains the 2 metre separation between the clocks? Are they connected by a rigid bar or something? Can an observer between the clocks  read both of them? Have the clocks been [Einstein-synchronized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation) to each other?

Comment: There is always ambiguity in time. This is what is called the principle of "relativity of simultaneity". Clocks with relative movement will not agree one with each other..

Answer (score 0):

If the clocks and the observer have the same gravitational potential, and aren't moving relative to each other, they will all track time the same. If the observer is closer to one clock than to the other, when they were synchronized, then a small difference could be observed. But the difference would not grow, as they are experiencing time the same.